# Change Share Dialog format in React Native FBSDK

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

How to change format of Facebook's ShareDialog from:
[image: image to the left and text to the right]

(image to the left and text to the right) to this format:

[image: image on top, text bottom and CTA button]

(image on top, text bottom and CTA button) ?

I'd wish to have a banner image instead of a square thumbnail like in the above image. Is there another name for that type of post?

I'm using the ShareDialog from [React Native FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) like this:

```
ShareDialog.canShow(shareLinkContent).then(
  function(canShow) {
    if (canShow) {
      return ShareDialog.show( shareLinkContent );
    }
  }
).then(
  function(result) {
    if (! result.isCancelled && undefined !== result.postId) {
       alert('Share operation was cancelled');
     } else {
       alert('Share was successful with postId: ' + result.postId);
     }
  },
  function(error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error);
  }
);
```

Comment: are you using the correct size and proportions for the image, according to the facebook docs?

Comment: @luschn I'm using 256x256px. I'm looking on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios but not seeing any recommended values

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe - Using a wider image did the trick. Such a simple answer!